# How can use same jrxml file with Java Code.?

Tags: java, ireport

I am using

> filename.jrxml

file to create a simple report with

> itext4.8.0

and it is working fine but i am passing parameter like this.

> $P{userId}]

Now i will want to use same

> filename.jrxml

With java code How can i achieve this ? My main concern is how can we pass parameter value as in ireport when i am running report in ireport it is opening popup for parameter and i am entering value .But in Java code how can pas that parameter?

**Note:-I dont want to pass connection with reports.**

Comment: any one know how can resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Solution in this [blog entry](http://suhasjavablog.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/jasper-reports-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Download jasperreport engine

```
final Map<String,Object> parameter = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameter.put("userId", 1l);
JasperFillManager.fillReport("filename.jasper", parameter, getData());

// set your own params for this method
public JRDatasource getData() { 
  // initialize a collection of Objects
  // Oh yes the query
  final Query query = getQuery("from SomeObject");
  final List<SomeObject> collection = (List<SomeObject>)query.list();
  return new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(collection);
}
```

Another possibility

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameter, connection);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply .What is getData() Here? Also query is part of fileName.jrxml file .

Comment: I have query inside jrxml file

Comment: The JRBeanCollectionDataSource is your new Dataset for the report the query inside of your report is ignored

Comment: But i want to use same query which i wrote inside the jrxml fie